# passing a list as input

Tags: python, for-loop, input

I have this simple Celsius to Fahrenheit code. I am having trouble creating a list of 10 days to be output. I can put one input and it give me Fahrenheit temperature but I'm blanking out on how to input a list of the 10 days to be output the calculation and if its cool or warm.

```
tmp = int(input("Input the  temperature you like to convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit? (e.g.,10) : "))
lst = [tmp]
i = 0
for i in range(len(lst)):
    lst[i] = (lst[i] * 1.8) + 32
    print(lst, "This is the fahrenheit temps")

if tmp < 0:
    print('Freezing weather.\n')
elif tmp < 10:
    print('Very cold weather.\n')
elif tmp < 20:
    print('Cool weather\n')
elif tmp < 30:
    print('Normal temps.\n')
elif tmp < 40:
    print("It's hot outside.\n")
else:
    print("You should properly stay inside")
```

Comment: Would you say that the problem you're facing has more to do with passing a list as input and less to do with the fact that you expect temperature data? If so, I recommend editing the title of your question to reflect that

Comment: @PaulH Thank you. I just did that.

Comment: I'll give you a hint: `"23,25,12,56".split()`

Comment: Hint 2: `str.split()` returns a list of _strings_. You need them to be numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I remade your code as per your needs

```py
temps = map(float, input("Input the temperature you'd like to convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit: ").split(',')) #split it with comma (,) and then convert every item into float
for temp in temps: #loop through the values
    fahrenite = temp * 9/5 + 32 #calculate
#blah blah
    if temp< 0:
        extra = "Freezing weather."
    elif temp< 10:
        extra = "Very cold weather."
    elif temp< 20:
        extra = "Cool weather"
    elif temp< 30:
        extra = "Normal temps."
    elif temp< 40:
        extra = "It's hot outside."
    else:
        extra = "You should properly stay inside"
#print everything
    print(f"{temp}℃  in Fahrenheit is {fahrenite}℉  that is {extra}")
```

And one more thing......use comma (,) to seperate your inputs

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to separate different temps into different input variables, and append them to a list in kind, then iterate through the list with your function.

Like so:

```
inputting = True
temps = []
while inputting:
    temp = int(input("Temp"))
    temps.append(temp)
    cond = input("continue? y/n")
    if cond in "Nn":
        inputting = False

def c_to_f(temperature):
    return temperature * 1.8 + 32

for temp in temps:
    print(c_to_f(temp))
```